# Login loop with database check in c++

Tags: c++, database, authentication

I have a database with 2 rows. Login is working perfectly for the first row saying if the password is matching or not. However it does not work for the second record. Here is a code that I am using:

```
TLogowanie->First();


   for(int i = 1; i < TLogowanie->RecordCount; i++) {
       if(TLogowanie->FieldByName("Username")->AsString == FormWybor->ComboBox1->Text)
        if(TLogowanie->FieldByName("Password")->AsString == Password->Text) {

            Label2->Caption = i;
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        else{
            TLogowanie->Next();
            }
   }
```

TLogowanie is TADOTable RecordCount is perfectly showing 2 records in database, Label2 is showing that the for loop worked. I tried it in 2 places before break and before next. Before break shows the number 1, before next it shows 2. So my assumption is that the loop is working.

What is wrong with the code? I'm working on RAD Studio (c++ builder)

Comment: If you format your code properly, you'd first be able to see that the `else` goes with the inner `if`, so it will only advance if the `username` is correct … There may be other problems, but that's the first thing I see.

Comment: you're breaking out of the loop, so you're only gonna process the first item that matches all your criteria.

Comment: I like to use the [Allman indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style). It makes scope errors brutally obvious